# Tensorflow: Changing the activations that affect backpropagation

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation

Is there a way in Tensorflow that I can change the hidden node activations to a different value during backpropagation? That is, suppose a node in a layer outputted a value 'a1' during the forward propagation. Then during backpropagation, when the gradients update reaches this node, I want it to use a different value as activation (say 'a2') so that whole backpropagation process will happen like it was 'a2' during the forward propagation.

I know that we can create/modify custom gradients, but here I need to replace the value of hidden node activation during backprop.

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved in number of ways. The most straightforward one is to use `tf.cond()` with boolean placeholder for which you're going to feed different values (`True`, `False`) during forward and backward passes. Following example uses `tf.nn.relu()` during forward pass and `tf.nn.sigmoid()` during backpropagation:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([[-1.551, -1.469], [1.022, 1.664]], dtype=np.float32)
y_train = np.array([1, 0], dtype=int)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])

with tf.name_scope('network'):
    fc1 = tf.layers.dense(x, units=2)

    # `isforward` is a placeholder that defines what activation
    # are you going to use. If `True` `tf.nn.relu` is used.
    # Otherwise, `tf.nn.sigmoid` is used. 
    isforward = tf.placeholder_with_default(True, shape=())

    activation = tf.cond(isforward,
                         true_fn=lambda: tf.nn.relu(fc1), # forward pass
                         false_fn=lambda: tf.nn.sigmoid(fc1)) # backprop
    logits = tf.layers.dense(activation, units=2)

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    loss_fn = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)

with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(loss_fn)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_fn)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    loss_val = sess.run(loss_fn, feed_dict={x:x_train,
                                            y:y_train,
                                            isforward:True}) # forward
    _ = sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x:x_train,
                                      y:y_train,
                                      isforward:False}) # backward
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the method. But my problem is slightly different. Here a different activation function is used when forward alone and another when we are training. For me, during the training itself, I want to use a forward function which is will compute the loss value, but during the weight update phase(this is what I meant by backprop), use a different activation value at each layer.

Comment: `loss_val=...` is forward pass with `relu`.  `_ = sess.run(...)` is a backward pass with `softmax`. It does what you asked.

Comment: My understanding is `loss_val = sess.run(loss_fn, feed_dict={x:x_train, y:y_train, isforward:True}) # forward` is where the we use `relu` for forward pass. Now `_ = sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x:x_train, y:y_train, isforward:False}) # backward` is where the `sigmoid` is getting activation. But here, the activations are from sigmoid when computing the loss. What I'm looking for is when the activations for during the computation of loss function is `relu`, but when SGD updates the weights, it should see like `sigmoid` was there.